# Creating a random blanket pattern using matrices

Tags: r, matrix, combinatorics

My partner has asked me to help her design a pattern for a blanket with the following rules:

1. It is a square blanket comprising 169 small squares (13 by 13)
2. There are 13 colours available to use (a - m)
3. 3 **different** colours are required per square (and the order of colours does not matter; e.g. "a,b,c" == "b,c,a")
4. For each small square there are 2 sets of colours that cannot be all together; Set 1 (a,b,c,d) and Set 2 (g,h,j,m). E.g. a small square cannot be a,b,c but can be a,b,e
5. **When designing the blanket each square can not be orthogonally adjacent to a square which contains any of the same colours (diagonals are fine)**
6. EDIT: Ideally each small square is only used once.

I have managed to do steps 1-4 above (see code below), but I am totally stumped with how to programmatically do step 5. I know I could do it by brute force or trial and error (or just by hand), but I was hoping there was a cleverer way to solve this.

Would anyone be able to help?

If that is possible to solve I then have a couple of subsequent questions:

1. How can I extend the solution for n colours and [i,j] matrices?
2. How can I obtain random solutions for given parameters (since I am assuming there is not a single solution for the colours and matrix size provided)?

Here is my working thus far:

```
# Generate the entire list of unique colour combinations (regardless of order).
col_list_combination <- as.data.frame(t(combn(letters[1:13], 3)))

# There are 2 sets where no combination is allowed:
excl_sets <- t(combn(letters[1:4], 3)) %>%
  rbind(t(combn(letters[c(7, 8, 10, 13)], 3))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# Setting the column names for my own sanity.
colnames(col_list_combination) <- colnames(excl_sets) <- c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")

# Removing those combinations that are not allowed
col_list_combination %<>% 
  anti_join(excl_sets, by = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary"))

# An attempt to figure out which combinations are allowed for a single square.
abe_neighbours <- col_list_combination %>%
  filter(Primary != "a" & Secondary != "a" & Tertiary != "a") %>%
  filter(Primary != "b" & Secondary != "b" & Tertiary != "b") %>%
  filter(Primary != "e" & Secondary != "e" & Tertiary != "e")
```

EDIT: The output desired would be a 13 by 13 matrix where each cell of the matrix is a triple code for a set of three colours, restricted in placement by the rules above. For example, something like:

```
tibble(c("abe", "ghm"), c("cki", "adf"))
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: @JosephWood - edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of thinking and work I believe I have come up with a solution:

```
# Generate the entire list of unique colour combinations (regardless of order). (Rule 3)
col_list_combination <- as.data.frame(t(combn(letters[1:13], 3)))

# There are 2 sets where no combination is allowed (Rule 4):
excl_sets <- t(combn(letters[1:4], 3)) %>%
  rbind(t(combn(letters[c(7, 8, 10, 13)], 3))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# Setting the column names for my own sanity.
colnames(col_list_combination) <- colnames(excl_sets) <- c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")

# Removing those combinations that are not allowed (Rule 4)
col_list_combination %<>% 
  anti_join(excl_sets, by = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")) %>%
  mutate(con_cat = paste(Primary, Secondary, Tertiary)) %>%
  select(con_cat)
```

Thus far I have just been creating the list of possible colour triples. Now I will attempt to create the blanket.

```
# First create the blank matrix of the size you wish (Rule 1 for this example).
output_matrix <- matrix(NA,13,13)

# Next set a random starting seed in the top left-most cell (this allows for random variations on output).
output_matrix[1,1] <- sample(col_list_combination %>% pull(con_cat), 1)

#create an empty vector for the "used" squares so that they do not get re-used (Rule 6).
used_combinations <- c()

#iterate over all columns and rows.
for(i in 1:nrow(output_matrix)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(output_matrix)) {

    #for each cell, figure out the colours of the cell above and to the left (since we are working left to right and top to bottom)
    split_cells <- strsplit(c(output_matrix[i, ifelse(j == 1, j, j-1)], 
                              output_matrix[ifelse(i == 1, i, i-1), j]), " ") %>% 
      unlist()
    split_cells <- split_cells[!is.na(split_cells)] #need to remove NAs since some cells do not have a cell above or to the left.

    #the number of non-allowed neighbour colours will either be 3 or 6 (I am ignoring duplicates for simplicity)
    if(length(split_cells) == 3) {
      cell_neighbours <- col_list_combination %>%
        filter(!con_cat %in% used_combinations) %>% #removes any that have been used already
        filter(!grepl(split_cells[1], con_cat) & 
                 !grepl(split_cells[2], con_cat) & 
                 !grepl(split_cells[3], con_cat)) %>%
        pull()
    } else if(length(split_cells) == 6) {
      cell_neighbours <- col_list_combination %>%
        filter(!con_cat %in% used_combinations) %>% removes any that have been used already.
        filter(!grepl(split_cells[1], con_cat) & 
                 !grepl(split_cells[2], con_cat) & 
                 !grepl(split_cells[3], con_cat) &
                 !grepl(split_cells[4], con_cat) &
                 !grepl(split_cells[5], con_cat) &
                 !grepl(split_cells[6], con_cat)) %>%
        pull()
    }
    cell_neighbours

    #select the new combination.
    new_combination <- sample(cell_neighbours, 1)

    #add the new combination to the appropriate cell.
    output_matrix[i,j] <- new_combination

    #update the used comnbination vector.
    used_combinations <- c(used_combinations, new_combination)
  }
}
output_matrix
```

I believe this works as intended, and can be extended for any matrix size, colour numbers, and allows for multiple variable output matrices.

I am pretty sure the code could be written more efficiently though...